# Get errors when aptitude update

Tags: debian, apt, aptitude, crunchbang

I get the following errors when `aptitude update`. These errors are after non-error updates. What do I do to fix this, but not remove the ppas, etc?

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net  Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net  Translation-en_CA
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net  Translation-en
Fetched 520 kB in 2s (206 kB/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/dists/wheezy/Release: Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-back/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/dists/stable/Release: Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-back/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/dists/wheezy-updates/Release: Unable to find expected entry 'non-free/binary-back/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/dists/wheezy-proposed-updates/Release: Unable to find expected entry 'non-free/binary-back/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.linuxmint.com/dists/debian/Release: Unable to find expected entry 'import/binary-back/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.crunchbang.org/waldorf/dists/waldorf/Release: Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-back/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-2/ubuntu/dists/lucid/Release: Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-back/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/wheezy-backports/Release: Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-back/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch http://repository.violetsky.ch/steam/dists/wheezy/Release: Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-back/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch http://mozilla.debian.net/dists/wheezy-backports/Release: Unable to find expected entry 'iceweasel-release/binary-back/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/wheezy/updates/Release: Unable to find expected entry 'non-free/binary-back/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/wheezy/Release: Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-back/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net///download.learnfree.eu/repository/skss/Packages: 404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
E: Couldn't rebuild package cache

W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://http.debian.net/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/http.debian.net_debian_dists_wheezy_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://http.debian.net/debian/ wheezy/contrib amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/http.debian.net_debian_dists_wheezy_contrib_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://http.debian.net/debian/ wheezy/non-free amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/http.debian.net_debian_dists_wheezy_non-free_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://http.debian.net/debian/ wheezy/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/http.debian.net_debian_dists_wheezy_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://http.debian.net/debian/ wheezy/contrib i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/http.debian.net_debian_dists_wheezy_contrib_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://http.debian.net/debian/ wheezy/non-free i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/http.debian.net_debian_dists_wheezy_non-free_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to update the package lists to correct these missing files
```

Comment: `http://ppa.launchpad.net///download.learnfree.eu/repository/skss/Packages` looks _very_ malformed to me.

Comment: Oh yeah, that looks pretty messed up!

Comment: If this is still an issue, you need to show us the contents of your ``/etc/sources.list` file and of any files in `/etc/apt/sources.d`. It looks like you're trying to use Ubuntu PPAs  on Debian and that won't work.

Answer (score 3):

Your `source.list` file is wrong. It should look like this :

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy main
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy main

deb http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy-updates main
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy-updates main

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
```

Correct your file and re-run `aptitude update`.

Read more : https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList

Comment: I would do that but I have stuff in the source.list like the googletalk plug in, sublime-text-2, the Mozilla-backports for iceweasel, etc. What would happen if I removed them, I cannot get updates for those applications anymore?

Comment: Don't remove them. Correct the syntax instead. Remember, the error message says : `Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file`. This was just an example.

Comment: didn't work. Every tried with the other sources removed but still get the same error. Though I did get these new errors: E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
E: Couldn't rebuild package cache

Comment: Is there a `source.list.d` directory with files in it ? If yes, look in those files.

Comment: yes there is. heres whats inside: http://i.imgur.com/Derl4AC.png

Comment: Ok, so one (or more) of those files seems to be wrong.

Comment: what do you suggest I do?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your `/etc/sources.list` to this (taken from [here](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList)):

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy main
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy main

deb http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy-updates main
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy-updates main

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
```

Then, try again apt-get update. If everything works as expected, add the extra lines you had (for Iceweasel etc) back into the file one by one. That way you can identify the malformed line if it is not obvious.

Comment: Who is "they" and who is "we"? Maybe you can try and salvage this answers by making it less verbose and more concrete, reference files by their full path (or indicate in which directory things are) etc. Does the OP have to set the contents of `sources.list` (in `/etc/apt`) to just that URL?